# Компонент не видит данные в локальном state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мысль такая: в `ComponentDidMount` получаем данные из `API`, записываем в `state` и используем потом внутри компонента для построения графика. Проблема следующая:
после того, как данные были записаны в `state`, взять их внутри `render()` не представляется возможным. Если вызвать `console.log(this.state.metricaGoalsData[0].data[0].metrics)`, то будет ошибка, мол `data` не существует

Код такой:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class MetricaGoals extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      metricaGoals          : [],
      metricaGoalsData      : [],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    const OATH_TOKEN = 'token';
    const PROJECT_ID = '23077159';

    fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/counter/23077159/goals?oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let acc = [];
      const promisses = [];
      this.setState({metricaGoals: data.goals});
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.metricaGoals.length; i++) {
        promisses.push(
          fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data/bytime?date1=2018-06-13&date2=2018-07-13&group=day&metrics=ym:s:goal${this.state.metricaGoals[i].id}conversionRate,ym:s:goal${this.state.metricaGoals[i].id}reaches&id=${PROJECT_ID}&oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
        );
      }

      return Promise.all(promisses);
    })
    .then(metricaGoalData => {
      const data = metricaGoalData
      this.setState({
        metricaGoalsData: data
      })
      console.log(this.state.metricaGoalsData[0].data[0].metrics[0]); // Тут хорошо
    })
  }

  render() {
    const getDateArray = function(start, end) {
      var
        arr = new Array(),
        dt = new Date(start);
      while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt).getFullYear() + ' / ' + (new Date(dt).getMonth()+1) + ' / ' + new Date(dt).getDate());
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      }
      return arr;
    }

    const startDate = new Date('2018-06-13')
    const endDate = new Date('2018-07-13')
    const visitorsArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate)
    return (
      <div className="MetricaGoals">
        <h2>Цели:</h2>
        <ul className="goals__list">
          {
            this.state.metricaGoals.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <li key={item.id}>
                  <div className="goals__name">{item.name}</div>
                  <div className="goals__id">{item.id}</div>
                  <div className="chart__wrapper">
                    <Bar
                      data={(canvas) => {
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
                        return {
                          labels: visitorsArr,
                          datasets: [{
                            label: 'Посещаемость',
                            data: this.state.metricaGoalsData[index].data[0].metrics[0], // А тут ошибка
                          }]
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MetricaGoals;
```

Как прокинуть записанные в `state` данные внутрь `render()`?

Comment: Так они де асинхронно сохраняются. Конечно при первом рендере их нет

Comment: @AlexeyTen Асинхронно, да. Но как узнать, что они загрузились и можно рендерить дальше?

Comment: Проверять, что данных ещё нет и рендерить заглушку. Когда данные появятся сработает setState и компонент перерендерится

Comment: @AlexeyTen для этого понадобится componentDidUpdate() ? Вообще как это реализуется? Я нашел один способ `return (this.state && this.state.data && <div> ... </div>`, но он все равно ошибку выкидывает

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин не понадобится. Проверяете в рендере наличие данных. Если их нет, то выводите "Loading...", как только фетч получил данные, то выполняется setState, который автоматически вызовет рендер. При этом вызове данные уже будут в стейте и отрисуются

Comment: Хм. Кажется вам надо прочитать учебник по реакту и асинхронным событиям. Конкретно тут я не понимаю зачем бы понадобился componentDidUpdate

Comment: @AlexeyTen учебник - это хорошо, но когда до практики дело доходит, все куда-то улетучивается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо отслеживать наличие данных в рендере. Поскольку загрузка асинхронна, первый рендер происходит с пустыми данными. Отсюда и ошибка

```
class MetricaGoals extends Component {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
    fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/counter/23077159/goals?oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
    ....
    .then(metricaGoalData => {
      const data = metricaGoalData
      this.setState({
        metricaGoalsData: data
      })
    })
  }

  showLoading() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  showData() {
     return (<div className="MetricaGoals">
        <h2>Цели:</h2>
        <ul className="goals__list">
          {
            this.state.metricaGoals.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <li key={item.id}>
                  <div className="goals__name">{item.name}</div>
                  <div className="goals__id">{item.id}</div>
                  <div className="chart__wrapper">
                    <Bar
                      data={(canvas) => {
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
                        return {
                          labels: visitorsArr,
                          datasets: [{
                            label: 'Посещаемость',
                            data: this.state.metricaGoalsData[index].data[0].metrics[0], // А тут ошибка
                          }]
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.metricaGoalsData && this.showData();}
        {!this.state.metricaGoalsData && this.showLoading();}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MetricaGoals;
```

Comment: Все равно не видно `data`. `metricaGoalsData` выглядит [так](https://yadi.sk/i/jpzXBjD_3aRNeM)

Comment: поместите console.log(this.state.metricaGoalsData); в рендер и посмотрите когда и какие данные туда приходят и проверяйте отсутствие данных

Comment: все выводит, как на скрине сразу после отрисовки графиков

Comment: т.е. стейт передается в рендер